# Why isn't my rig working at all?

Tags: modeling, rigging

I'm trying to make a character model. When I try to parent the model to the rig, it says it worked but when I try to pose it, the model doesn't move or deform, at all. my process was: make the model > join pieces of model into one object > make metarig (basic human) > set up rig > make the rig parent of the model with "Automatic weights."

here's a link to the project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r0Vg4sNNSJEkzCE7F9_ewxF11PSLtumv/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First apply the transforms of both the object and armature, then select the object, go in *Edit* mode, select all and <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* with a distance of 0.001. Also put your *Armature* modifier above the *Subdivision Surface*.